# How do I run "pandas.read_csv" with the ''delimeter" inside the definition of a generator function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

CSV file size is so large (several GB), so I wanted to slice the row by steps and modify each sliced `DataFrames` with pivot and then combine the `DataFrames`.

I used a generator function for slicing the data by rows but I was not able to get stuck in the `'delimeter'` argument in `pandas.read_csv` as below.

```
import pandas as pd

def generator():
  for x in range(0,366130,11):
    yield pd.read_csv(filename, nrows = x, delimeter='\x01', header=None)

g = generator()
df = next(g)

df
```

When I ran this code, I got the following error in ipython:

```
TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-7e0eb8a3d8b6> in <module>
----> 1 df1 = next(g)
      2 df1

<ipython-input-75-fae533ab2013> in generator()
      2 #      print("homework_1_1")
      3     for x in range(0,366130,11):
----> 4       yield pd.read_csv(filename, nrows = x, delimeter='\x01', header=None)
      5 
      6 g = generator()

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimeter'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you spelled `delimiter` wrong, that's the issue

Comment: `nrows` specifies how many rows to read, not which row.  As written your `generator` opens the file fresh each iteration, reading `x` rows each time (an increasingly large number).

Answer (score 0):

simply break the file into chunks

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

instead of taking entire dataset in memory all at once, it is better to break in chunks

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

OR

also you can use Dask Library

https://pythondata.com/dask-large-csv-python/

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

filename = '311_Service_Requests.csv'
df = dd.read_csv(filename, dtype='str')
```